# MySQL Full Text Search Safety

Tags: mysql

Is this code safe from sql injection?

```
$search = $_GET ['search'];
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM table WHERE MATCH (id,keywords) AGAINST ('$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
$query->execute();
```

**UPDATE:**
According to answer below I changed my code and now it is:

```
$search = $_GET ['search'];
$tbl_name = 'my_table_name';

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM $tbl_name WHERE MATCH (id,keywords) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
$query->bindValue(':search', $search . '*', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not safe against SQL injection because you neither use parameter binding nor you escape user input properly.

I recommend you to have a look at http://bobby-tables.com/ to get a better understanding of how SQL injection works and how to write code which is safe against SQL injection in the programming language of your choice.

Comment: I changed my code, Is it safe now? Thank you

Comment: @MishaAbesadze: I cannot see anything obvious wrong with this code so I think it should be safe against SQL injection.